# Only display IMPORTRANGE rows that match specific criteria

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

In Google Sheets I'm using `IMPORTRANGE` to pull in a large list of data (about 400 rows, 6 columns) and I want to only display rows where column D matches `EXAMPLE TEXT`.

For example: if column D of the `IMPORTRANGE` source says "Value A" then that row is successfully displayed on the destination sheet.

Is this a possible?

Answer (score 2):

The QUERY function will do what I want.  I had no idea that I could use database like functions in Sheets.

`=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("insert_url","Range"),"Select Col1, Col2 Where Col4='Value'")`

Comment: Also you could use the FILTER function -> [FILTER - Docs Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)